# Why do my quaternions constantly flip my object while rotating?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, quaternions

I am rotating points using quaternions of the form `[w x y z]`. My initial quaternion is the identity, `[1 0 0 0]`.

When I press Q, I multiple my current quaternion by `[0.1 0 1 0]` to get a rotation around the y-axis. This works correctly, for the most part.

However, if I continue to rotate (as long as I hold down Q), the rectangle I am rotating constantly flips back and forth producing a ghost-like image of itself. It appears as if it is drawing itself forwards, backwards, forwards, backwards, forwards, backwards, etc.

The following is the code I use to generate the transformation matrix from the quaternion:

```
1 - 2yy - 2zz    2xy - 2wz    2xz - 2wy
2xy + 2wz    1 - 2xx - 2zz    2yz - 2wx
2xz - 2wy        2yz + 2wx    1 - 2xx - 2yy
```

As I said, though, it seems to be rotating correctly. It just flips back and forth very quickly. (So quickly that I was unable to capture an animated GIF of the problem.)

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you realize the '0.1' angle is in radians, not degrees?

Comment: @andand Yes - it rotates at a decent speed. Does that affect anything other than the amount of rotation?

Comment: Also, do you ensure the vector part is normalized (i.e. unit lenght)?

Comment: You don't have a lot of detail in the question, so I'm just mentioning some common problems which might be of help.

Comment: @andand I understand, thanks. I do normalize after multiplication.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest at this point, then is to compare the results you're getting with an axis / angle formulation of a rotation matrix (as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Axis_and_angle)

Comment: Also, I mis-spoke earlier... the entire quaternion (not just he vector part) needs to be normalized.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect?

Comment: One other possibility comes to mind.  If you are multiplying the rotation quaternion repeatedly AND applying that rotation to the already rotated rectangle, your rotation angle in increasing as the square of the number of iterations, rather than linearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rotating a quaternion on 1 axis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436764/rotating-a-quaternion-on-1-axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your equation is off by a sign in the top right corner, does this work for you

```
1.0 - 2.0yy - 2.0zz,       2.0xy - 2.0zw,       2.0xz + 2.0yw
      2.0xy + 2.0zw, 1.0 - 2.0xx - 2.0zz,       2.0yz - 2.0xw
      2.0xz - 2.0yw,       2.0yz + 2.0xw, 1.0 - 2.0xx - 2.0yy
```

Comment: I was calculating my axis rotations incorrectly. There is a link to another question that contains an accurate answer for computing them.